# JQUERY - ¿Como recuperar y modificar datos de select dinamico?

Tags: jquery, laravel-blade

me encuentro en un problema, esoty trabajando con 4 select anidados dinamicamente, el tema que ahora debo hacer el update y en caso de querer modificar no me aparecen las demas opciones como podría hacerlo para que funcione correcto.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#paises").change(function(){
        var categoria = $(this).val();
        $.get('/buscarRegion/'+categoria, function(data){
          //esta el la peticion get, la cual se divide en tres partes. ruta,variables y funcion
          console.log(data);

            var producto_select = '<option value="">Seleccione Región</option>'
              for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
                producto_select+='<option value="'+data[i].id +'">'+data[i].nombre+'</option>';
              }

              $("#regiones").html(producto_select);
        });
      });

      $("#regiones").change(function(){
          var region = $("#regiones").val();
          $.get('/buscarProvincia/'+region, function(data){
            //esta el la peticion get, la cual se divide en tres partes. ruta,variables y funcion
            console.log(data);

              var select_prov = '<option value="">Seleccione Provincia</option>'
                for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
                  select_prov+='<option value="'+data[i].id +'">'+data[i].nombre+'</option>';
                }
                $("#provincias").html(select_prov);
          });
        });

        $("#provincias").change(function(){
          var comuna = $("#provincias").val();
          console.log(comuna);
          $.get('/buscarComuna/'+comuna, function(data){
            //esta el la peticion get, la cual se divide en tres partes. ruta,variables y funcion
            console.log(data);

              var select_comuna = '<option value="">Seleccione Comuna</option>'
                for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
                  select_comuna+='<option value="'+data[i].id +'">'+data[i].nombre+'</option>';
                }

                $("#comunas").html(select_comuna);
          });
        });

    });
```

Esta es la parte del HTML para editar. Al cargar los datos del jquery no se como hacerlos aparecer para region, provincia y comuna, es primera vez que hago algo que tenga que ver con llenado de select y que funcione.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label>País</label>
                    @if(!isset( $traerPropiedad->idPais))
                        <select class="form-control" name="cboPais" id="paises">
                            <option>Seleccione País</option>
                            @foreach ($paises as $pais)
                                <option value="{{ $pais->idPais }}">{{ $pais->nombrePais}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    @else
                        <select class="form-control" name="cboPais" id="paises">
                            <option>Seleccione País</option>
                            @foreach ($paises as $pais)
                                <option value="{{ $pais->idPais }}" {{ ($pais->idPais == $traerPropiedad->idPais) ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{ $pais->nombrePais}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label>Región</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="cboRegion" id="regiones">
                        <option>Seleccione Región</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label>Provincia</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="cboProvincia" id="provincias">
                        <option>Seleccione Provincia</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label>Comuna</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="cboComuna" id="comunas">
                        <option>Seleccione Comuna</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Actualmente trabajo la vista con plantillas blade. Agradeceria de mucho la ayuda.

Comment: Como en la vista de modificar tambien tendras tu codigo de javascript para ir actualizando los selectores dependientes, entonces cuando cargas la vista, en el controlador, consulta las provincias, de acuerdo al id pais del registro, lo mismo con comunas, consultas por el id de provincia que tiene el registro.

Comment: Sigues necesitando ayuda para mostrarte cómo?

Comment: Creo que si ya que al final no se si como lo hize estaria correcto que en vez de recuperarlo del JQUERY lo tire directo al formulario como fue en el caso de pais lo hize @FernandoUrban